# After editing user details, when submiting need to redirect to user page with the fresh edit details

Tags: laravel, routes, reload

i'm facing a simple but hard routing problem! so i'm building an app with laravel using blade. My problem is simple, when i'm editing the user details, i'm redirecting to my user page as i want but the informations are not updating! how can i do that? i tried so many things that i can't see wha't wrong anymore!

Can someone help me understand my mistakes? thanks! a french newbie :)

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-block"><a href="{{redirect()->route('users.show',['id'=>$user->id])}}"></a>Valider la modification</button>
```

Comment: Remove `redirect()->`, but there are other issues, like having an `<a>` inside a `button type="submit"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `href` attribute of the `<a>` inside the `<button>` takes precedence over the `<form>`'s `action` attribute, therefore your update action is never called. You should perform the redirect in your route action, e.g. the controller:

```php
class UserController extends Controller
{
    // other actions

    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $user = User::find($id);
        $user->fill($request->all()); // Do not fill unvalidated data

        if (!$user->save()) {
            // Handle error

            // Redirect to the edit form while preserving the input
            return redirect()->back()->withInput();
        }

        // Redirect to the 'show' page on success
        return redirect()->route('users.show', ['id' => $user->id]);
    }

    // more actions
}
```

Your form should then look similar to this:

```html
<form action="{{ route('user.update', ['id' => $user->id]) }}" method="POST">
    <!-- Use @method and @csrf depending on your route's HTTP verb and if you have CSRF protection enabled -->
    @method('PUT')
    @csrf
    <!-- Your form fields -->
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-block">
        Valider la modification
    </button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it's work ans i can see my misunderstanding!